# Commit при вызове процедуры postgresql через oracle dblink

Tags: postgresql

Коллеги, подскажите, пожалуйста. Не фиксируются данные при вызове процедуры postgresql через oracle dblink

1) Создал простейшую процедуру в БД postgresql

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.test_insert(i_id integer)
RETURNS integer
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
DECLARE
begin

insert into tts.test_ora_db(id) values(i_id);

return i_id;

EXCEPTION
WHEN others THEN
RAISE WARNING 'err. %  Errm: %', sqlstate, sqlerrm;
return sqlerrm;
END;
$function$
```

2) В БД Oracle создал процедуру для возможности вызова через DBlink процедур postgresql с входными параметрами

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION Call_Postgre_n(v_Func VARCHAR2) RETURN NUMBER IS
v_Cursor BINARY_INTEGER;
v_Nr BINARY_INTEGER;
v_Ret NUMBER;
BEGIN
v_Cursor := Dbms_Hs_Passthrough.Open_Cursor@Pgsql;

Dbms_Hs_Passthrough.Parse@Pgsql(v_Cursor,
'select ' || v_Func);
v_Nr := Dbms_Hs_Passthrough.Fetch_Row@Pgsql(v_Cursor);
Dbms_Hs_Passthrough.Get_Value@Pgsql(v_Cursor,
1,
v_Ret);
Dbms_Hs_Passthrough.Close_Cursor@Pgsql(v_Cursor);
RETURN v_Ret;
END;
```

3) Совершаю вызов

```
select Call_Postgre_n('public.test_insert(10)') as rez from dual
```

Вернуло 10

4) Снова в postgresql

```
select * from tts.test_ora_db;
```

Пусто!!!
Как же так? Прочитал кучу топиков, где пишут, что явно commit писать не требуется, до и не позволяется это в процедуре postgresql.

Comment: Хранимка в postgresql выполняется всегда в пределах транзакции, поэтому в её теле ни begin, ни commit не сделать. У вас очень плохая мысль заменить exception warning'ом - не надо так делать. Но это не непосредственная причина отката. Давайте посмотрим, что происходит на postgresql: включите `log_min_duration_statement = 0` и посмотрите лог postgresql. Должны будут быть запротоколированы все выполняемые запросы. Меня интересует, не делает ли oracle сначала неявно из своей хранимки begin

Comment: BEGIN действительно добавляется, как быть с этим??

Вот лог
< 2017-11-14 13:29:26.922 MSK >LOG:  duration: 1.375 ms  statement: select oid, typbasetype from pg_type where typname = 'lo'
< 2017-11-14 13:29:27.053 MSK >LOG:  duration: 0.175 ms  statement: show max_identifier_length
< 2017-11-14 13:29:27.161 MSK >LOG:  duration: 1.950 ms  statement: BEGIN;select public.test_insert(10)

Comment: ну как минимум добавить в теги релевантные теги для оракла - проблема именно там, надо или отучить делать begin или выяснить как скомандовать commit. Я могу только по pg-части ответить и здесь всё полностью закономерно: есть begin и нет commit - значит делаем rollback.

Comment: Получилось!! Так работает
select Call_Postgre_n('public.test_insert(10); commit;') as rez from dual